# To execute query in XML format using Microsoft dynamics CRM

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have designed a query using `Advanced Find` and downloaded the same using `Download Fetch XML` option.

After getting that XML, I made some changes in the downloaded XML file. Now, I want to run the query in the modified XML file, using `Microsoft Dynamics CRM`.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you have modified a fetch query I'd say you must use it in a queryexpression from an application that connects to the CRM using the wcf endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the FetchXml Tester utility from the [XRM Toolbox](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox). You can load the resulting xml into Excel if you want to look at it in tabular format.

There is also a way to manually push FetchXml into a view via the SDK or customization XML, but that is a bit more involved.